# Can you set OpenVPN to auto-connect to 'fallback' .ovpns in case the current one fails?

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn

I'm in Debian 7.8 Wheezy, and have installed openvpn from the stable repository.

I'd like to set up a system for another user (who does not have high computer literacy) where, if the primary server that I have configured (`/path/to/one.ovpn`) fails for some reason, I have a backup one (`/path/to/two.ovpn`) to automatically connect to instead, as a backup.

And maybe I give them ten .ovpn files (e.g. using free community servers from [VPN Gate](http://www.vpngate.net/en/)), to try really make sure the user is secured (assuming one of them works), without them having to manually do anything about it.

Is there a way in the default openvpn config, or some third-party GUI compatible with Debian, that can achieve this?

Or perhaps a script? (which I could then set to run at startup.)

Answer (score 4):

I think the best you can do  right now is to set up OpenVPN properly to inform it that there is second server, like this:

> Implementing a load-balancing/failover configuration Client
>
> The OpenVPN client configuration can refer to multiple servers for
>   load balancing and failover. For example:

```
remote server1.mydomain
remote server2.mydomain
remote server3.mydomain
```

> will direct the OpenVPN client to attempt a connection with server1,
>   server2, and server3 in that order. If an existing connection is
>   broken, the OpenVPN client will retry the most recently connected
>   server, and if that fails, will move on to the next server in the
>   list. You can also direct the OpenVPN client to randomize its server
>   list on startup, so that the client load will be probabilistically
>   spread across the server pool.

```
remote-random
```

> If you would also like DNS resolution failures to cause the OpenVPN
>   client to move to the next server in the list, add the following:

```
resolv-retry 60
```

> The 60 parameter tells the OpenVPN client to try resolving each remote
>   DNS name for 60 seconds before moving on to the next server in the
>   list.
>
> The server list can also refer to multiple OpenVPN server daemons
>   running on the same machine, each listening for connections on a
>   different port, for example:

```
remote smp-server1.mydomain 8000
remote smp-server1.mydomain 8001
remote smp-server2.mydomain 8000
remote smp-server2.mydomain 8001
```

> If your servers are multi-processor machines, running multiple OpenVPN
>   daemons on each server can be advantageous from a performance
>   standpoint.
>
> OpenVPN also supports the remote directive referring to a DNS name
>   which has multiple A records in the zone configuration for the domain.
>   In this case, the OpenVPN client will randomly choose one of the A
>   records every time the domain is resolved.

Source:
https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#loadbalance

Comment: This is useful, but what if one server is TCP and the other is UDP? - the above doesn't seem to allow for that, it's either all servers must be UDP or TCP. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: That's correct, unfortunately no work around I can think of. I'd unify the configs to UDP only though.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment but I wanted to add that according to [this page](https://openvpn.net/faq/how-do-i-set-up-my-profile-for-server-failover/), it is possible to specify the protocol for each `remote` entry.

> **How do I set up my profile for server failover?**
>
> You can provide OpenVPN with a list of servers to connect to. On
>   connection failure, OpenVPN will rotate through the list until it
>   finds a responsive server. For example, the following entries in the
>   profile will first try to connect to server A via UDP port 1194, then
>   TCP port 443, then repeat the process with server B. OpenVPN will
>   continue to retry until it successfully connects or hits the
>   Connection Timeout, which can be configured in the Preferences.
>
> ```
> remote server-a.example.tld 1194 udp
> remote server-a.example.tld 443 tcp
> remote server-b.example.tld 1194 udp
> remote server-b.example.tld 443 tcp
> ```

Answer (score 0):

See `<connection>` in https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage. This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it comes close and may be helpful to others.

> <connection> Define a client connection profile. Client connection
> profiles are groups of OpenVPN options that describe how to connect to
> a given OpenVPN server. Client connection profiles are specified
> within an OpenVPN configuration file, and each profile is bracketed by
> <connection> and </connection>. An OpenVPN client will try each
> connection profile sequentially until it achieves a successful
> connection.
>
> --remote-random can be used to initially "scramble" the connection list.
>
> Here is an example of connection profile usage:
>
> client dev tun
>
> <connection> remote 198.19.34.56 1194 udp </connection>
>
> <connection> remote 198.19.34.56 443 tcp </connection>
>
> <connection> remote 198.19.34.56 443 tcp http-proxy 192.168.0.8 8080
> </connection>
>
> <connection> remote 198.19.36.99 443 tcp http-proxy 192.168.0.8 8080
> </connection>
>
> persist-key persist-tun pkcs12 client.p12 remote-cert-tls server verb
> 3 First we try to connect to a server at 198.19.34.56:1194 using UDP.
> If that fails, we then try to connect to 198.19.34.56:443 using TCP.
> If that also fails, then try connecting through an HTTP proxy at
> 192.168.0.8:8080 to 198.19.34.56:443 using TCP. Finally, try to connect through the same proxy to a server at 198.19.36.99:443 using
> TCP.
>
> The following OpenVPN options may be used inside of a <connection>
> block:
>
> bind, connect-retry, connect-retry-max, connect-timeout,
> explicit-exit-notify, float, fragment, http-proxy, http-proxy-option,
> link-mtu, local, lport, mssfix, mtu-disc, nobind, port, proto, remote,
> rport, socks-proxy, tun-mtu and tun-mtu-extra.
>
> A defaulting mechanism exists for specifying options to apply to all
>  profiles. If any of the above options (with the exception
> of remote ) appear outside of a <connection> block, but in a
> configuration file which has one or more <connection> blocks, the
> option setting will be used as a default for <connection> blocks which
> follow it in the configuration file.
>
> For example, suppose the nobind option were placed in the sample
> configuration file above, near the top of the file, before the first
> <connection> block. The effect would be as if nobind were declared in
> all <connection> blocks below it.